# Why is my wallet in Maintenance mode?

Tags: wallet

My OMG wallet on Yobit.net is in maintenance. I get this message when I try to withdraw or lodge to the wallet. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

this happens sometimes on many exchanges. i have seen this also on poloniex and bittrex for other cryptocurrensies. this is usually a normal procedure. in a few days you should be able to deposit/withdraw your funds again.

Comment: Bittrex provides a prompt that advises that the wallet is in maintenance; the same happens on Binance but not so on Yobit.net; at least not in this instance with me. It would certainly reduce anxiety if Yobit would do likewise.